# Django: Why are some templates not detected?

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here. I'm working on a project with a couple of apps and, thus, have kept my templates at my project's level. Now, the issue here is some templates are not being detected at the corresponding urls. For instance, the template (`property_list.html`) corresponding to properties list is detected just fine at the relevant url (`/properties`), while neither `property_detail.html` nor `property_new.html` corresponding to `properties/new` and `properties/[insert property ID]` respectively are. Just for the record, Home, Sign up, Log in work just fine.

I have looked up similar instances, both here as well as at other places, but nothing seems to be pointing me in the direction I want. So, what gives?

A screenshot of the template structure is in the linked image below. Again, the folder is at root/project level.

**Template Structure**

[image]

**Project Settings (Template Section)**

```
# ...
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# ...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# ...
```

**Project Urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('agencies/', include('agencies.urls')),
    path('properties/', include('properties.urls')),
]
```

**Properties Urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.PropertyListView.as_view(), name='property_list'),
        path('new/', views.PropertyCreateView.as_view(), name='property_new'),
        path('<slug:pk>/', views.PropertyDetailView.as_view(), name='property_detail'),
]
```

**Properties Views**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Property

# Create your views here.
class PropertyListView(ListView):
        model = Property
        template_name = 'property_list.html'

class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Property
        template_name = 'property_detail.html'

class PropertyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Property
        template_name = 'property_new.html'
        fields = [
                'property_type', 
                'is_for_sale', 
                'cost', 
                'location', 
                'num_of_bedrooms', 
                'num_of_bathrooms', 
                'num_of_parking_spaces', 
                'num_of_garages',
                'has_pool',
                'has_waterfront',
                'has_elevator',
                'added_on',
        ]

        login_url = 'login'

        def form_valid(self, form):
                form.instance.author = self.request.user
                return super().form_valid(form)

# class PropertyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
#       model = Property
#       fields = ['title', 'body', ]
#       template_name = 'property_edit.html'
#       login_url = 'login'

# class PropertyDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
#       model = Property
#       template_name = 'property_delete.html'
#       success_url = reverse_lazy('property_list')
#       login_url = 'login'
#
```

Comment: What do you put in your URL when you try to access one of your views?

Comment: You need to write your html as 'dir/html', in this case, will be like:
`template_name = 'properties/property_new.html'`

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron Yes, thank you. That is what got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your settings you have `'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'))]` then by default django looks for file names under the directory named "templates" on your root.

In your templates directory structure you added another directory named `properties` which includes `property_list.html` so, for the `view` to find the template you have to specify the relative path starting `template` directory.

```
template_name = 'properties/property_list.html'
template_name = 'properties/property_new.html'
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Django standard is to create a "templates" folder for every app you have.

This templates folder should then contain yet another folder called like the app name.